# Android Keep thread alive questions

Tags: android, multithreading, tcp

I am building an Android App that will communicate over TCP with a server. I have a few ideas for implementation and I don't know which way would be best to go. I am new at this and my design is constantly evolving as I learn new things, so now I am looking for advice for how to best implement a solution to fulfill my goal.

Goal: Be able to:

1. send data to a server
2. Send data to a server and read the servers response.

   - Some information I send will be to give the server information, other will be to request information from the server.

Possible implementations:

- Thread Run() method constantly loops through checking if my send queue has something to send (and sending it if it does) then checking if I have anything to read back in.

  - Will this drain battery/burn CPU?
- Create a new thread each time I want to send/receive, the let it die once I have done 'send' or 'send + receive'

  - How should I synchronize the threads interactions with my one socket? Block making the next thread until this one finishes?
- Make a thread and call a send or send + receive method withing that thread each time I need to write or write + read

  - How do I keep the thread alive without burning battery/CPU?
  - should I use a queue to handle requests for transmitting data and should I synchronize reading from it until the current read/write is finished?

Any additional pointers, links, or warnings about potential issues would be much appreciated. Sample code is especially appreciate as I am just starting out with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've pointed there are several ways of achieving this, each of them has its advantages and weaknesses.

Leaving a connection open, or re-sending them very often will definitely make a difference in battery duration. If this is your case I'd think about batching some requests into one every certain amount of time. Here is a interesting [article](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html) about that.

I wrote some days ago about an approach I'm using very often which works pretty nicely. It can be as simple as it looks or set the basis for a whole API communication engine for your Android app. It is up to your needs. It is basically executing your requests in a pool of background threads, controlled by a service and notified within your activities or whatever you need.
Whenever you need to push a new requests it as simple as enqueueing it and setting the callback.
If you think that might work for you here I leave you a pair of links diving deeper into this.

http://ugiagonzalez.com/2012/07/02/theres-life-after-asynctasks-in-android/
http://ugiagonzalez.com/2012/08/03/using-runnables-queues-and-executors-to-perform-tasks-in-background-threads-in-android/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Your link led me to "Use Google Cloud Messaging as an Alternative to Polling" on the android dev site and that seems like it will be very useful for me as I will be updating to see the current status of my server very frequently (status changes about every 200-4000 ms on average while in use). If I combine your suggestions with what your link sent me to, I should be able to come up with a good solution.

Comment: Well, using push is one of the suggestions there, but the whole background of how the radio system works in Android is pretty valuable for me. 
Keep me up to date with your progress.

Comment: Yes, One of the pages you linked explained how the radio works, and that it stays fully powered for about 20s after each use. Progress with the app may be a little slow because this is a proof-of-concept project right now and my other work has to take higher priority. That said, I will keep you up-to-date as I move forward. If I want to make a "quick and dirty" implementation for now, then refactor for more reliable + better battery & CPU usage after I get the app running, do you think one of my original ideas is better than the others?

Comment: I'd go for this:
Make a thread and call a send or send + receive method withing that thread each time I need to write or write + read
How do I keep the thread alive without burning battery/CPU?
should I use a queue to handle requests for transmitting data and should I synchronize reading from it until the current read/write is finished?

For keepAlive, I'd set a timeout for the call to your server/API but not to your thread, which will find its end anyway.
I'd use the same thread for making the whole request (call + response) that way you receive your response and process it in the same thread

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, I will have a send method and a send + receive method in my thread in these will be timeouts so I don't get stuck in a "no response". Then do I start a new thread for each send or send/receive I want to send to the server? Thanks so much, this is extremely helpful... Is there a way I can give you more rep? I have upped your answer and accepted it so far..

Comment: I don't do this for reputation.It's nice as it is. It's good to see everybody's progress because I've faced the same things in the past.
You can just create a method that sends + receives with the only difference that in the case you don't need the response you just dont't wait for it. The call will be executed in the background until it finishes. You don't need to start a new thread for each request, just add it to your pool executor and this will manage threads on its own. If you read the 2 blog posts I wrote about this I guess you'll get a clear idea. Have a look to the service and ask back

Comment: Will do. I had begun to read the articles, but work got busy. I'll try this stuff and respond as soon as I get the chance. Thanks

Comment: Just an update.. I am out of town for work, so it will be a couple days until I can explore this and respond - but I will do so as soon as I am able.